# Cancel Lock Session Event

Tags: c#, session-state

Is it possible to cancel the Session Lock Event?

I have this code to detect if the session lock is thrown and it works. I just want to be able to cancel the session lock from happening.

My Code:
...

```
SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += new SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch);
```

...

```
void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
    {
        switch(e.Reason)
        {
            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock:
                startAlarm = true;
                alarm.Play();
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                this.Show();
                InfoText.Text = "PLEASE REMOVE YOUR ID CARD";
                break;

            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock:
                startAlarm = false;
                alarm.Stop();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think what you're trying to do isn't possible. SystemEvents are read-only (so said), they are just provided in order to shut your application down properly (or doing so other stuff) when needed, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Arnaud F says in the comment. It is impossible.